# How to display sqlite table values column as row in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-tablelayout

Now i am creating chart applications . I have to create chart based on sqlite table values . I have the following values in my database http://pastie.org/5114056 . I fetch all the data and stored into corresponding arrays. Now i want to display all the values in table view like this [image]

All the column value must be displayed as row values. And all the row values displayed as column values in dynamically. How can i do this? Can any body help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything for this?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476980/inserting-two-arrays-into-listview-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Hai all just follow this link you will get the proper output for displaying database base column values as row  [How to create a multiple column table view in android using java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080556/how-to-create-a-multiple-column-table-view-in-android-using-java-code)

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon here at Stack Overflow, as if the links ever went dead, the answer would become useless. Please include the important parts of the links here in the answer, and provide the links as further reference. If it is a link to a product or service, explain how you can use said product or service to answer the question rather than just providing a link